# Powershell/windows 10: how to count files inside a folder?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I think it's best described with an example

```
parent1 (located inside my documents)
  - folder1
    - test11.png
    - test11.txt
    - folder11
      - test111.png
    - folder12
      - test121.png
      - test122.png
  - folder2
    - test21.png
```

if I run the command/script supplying the path and the extension, the output should be:

```
folder1: 4
folder2: 1
```

If I don't supply the extension, all files will be counted.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please show some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Helping myself only works if I know where to start....

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `Get-ChildItem` and `Measure-Object` cmldets.

```
$RootDirectory = 'C:\Program Files (x86)'
Get-ChildItem $RootDirectory -Recurse -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $DirectoryName = $_.FullName
        $FilesCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryName -File | Measure-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Count 
        '{0}: {1}' -f $DirectoryName, $FilesCount
    }
```